# Microsoft Teams Bot-task module with arbitrary iframe-able web content?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've got a C# bot that already uses the SDK to create task modules using adaptive cards, but I wanted to try something out with arbitrary web content.  I've created the continue response like this (just putting an internet-accessible IIS page as the URL to test):

```
 {
    "Status": 200,
    "Body": {
        "task": {
            "value": {
                "title": "webTest",
                "url": "https://icechris.computertalkrnd.com/iisstart.htm",
                "card": null,
                "fallbackUrl": "https://icechris.computertalkrnd.com/iisstart.htm",
                "completionBotId": "BOT_ID"
            },
            "type": "continue"
        }
    }
}
```

If I return an adaptive card, my response looks like this:

```
{
    "Status": 200,
    "Body": {
        "task": {
            "value": {
                "title": null,
                "height": null,
                "width": null,
                "url": null,
                "card": {
                    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                    "contentUrl": null,
                    "content": {
                        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                        "version": "1.0",
                        "body": [CARD BODY]
                    },
                    "name": null,
                    "thumbnailUrl": null
                },
                "fallbackUrl": null,
                "completionBotId": null
            },
            "type": "continue"
        }
    }
}
```

Which renders fine (I clipped the card json for brevity).

I have the following in my bot manifest for valid domains:

```
"validDomains": [ "*.computertalkrnd.com", "icechris.computertalkrnd.com", "computertalkrnd.com", "computer-talk.com" ]
```

Is it just not possible to have a task module display arbitrary web content like this, or is there something else I'm missing in the response?  I noticed that the completionBotID isn't set for an adaptive card, but for the web case it doesn't make a difference if I set it or not.

I did pull up the dev tools in Teams and notice this when I tested the invoke:

```
2019-11-28T21:32:51.245Z AppsService: getInstalledAppForUser - Invalid appId specified
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:113
e.logMessage @ msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1
e.error @ msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1
t.getInstalledAppForUser @ msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1
t.getAppDefinitionFromCurrentContext @ msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1
t.getAppDefinitionFromCurrentContext @ msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1
t @ msteams-web-ng1.min.js:1
t @ msteams-web-ng1.min.js:1
invoke @ angular.min.js:36
R.instance @ angular.min.js:84
n @ angular.min.js:59
g @ angular.min.js:53
g @ angular.min.js:53
g @ angular.min.js:53
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:52
(anonymous) @ 2-vendor.min-40cd418b.js:138
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:154
e @ angular.min.js:40
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:43
setTimeout (async)
Zf.k.defer @ angular.min.js:43
f @ angular.min.js:154
(anonymous) @ 2-vendor.min-40cd418b.js:138
f @ angular.min.js:126
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:126
$eval @ angular.min.js:141
$digest @ angular.min.js:138
f.$digest @ msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1
$apply @ angular.min.js:141
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:92
x @ angular.min.js:96
w.onload @ angular.min.js:97
load (async)
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:97
r @ angular.min.js:93
g @ angular.min.js:90
f @ angular.min.js:126
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:126
$eval @ angular.min.js:141
$digest @ angular.min.js:138
f.$digest @ msteams-web-ng1-services.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:141
e @ angular.min.js:40
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:43
setTimeout (async)
Zf.k.defer @ angular.min.js:43
$evalAsync @ angular.min.js:141
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:125
g @ angular.min.js:126
then @ angular.min.js:127
t.markConversationAsRead @ msteams-web-ng1.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ msteams-web-ng1.min.js:1
$emit @ angular.min.js:143
n.$emit @ eventingService.min.js:1
a.invokeAppInUseEventIfNeeded @ appStateService.min.js:1
a.setPageVisible @ appStateService.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ appStateService.min.js:1
$emit @ angular.min.js:143
n.$emit @ eventingService.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ desktopEventsService.min.js:1
listenerWrapper @ C:\Users\cbardon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\resources\app.asar\lib\renderer\ipcRenderer.js:335
emit @ events.js:182
angular.min.js:113 TypeError: Cannot read property 'validDomains' of undefined
```

Looking at the response for an adaptive card though, I don't see anything significantly different between the two.

Comment: Yes, you can embed the arbitrary web content with in a task module but the url should be Iframe-able. You need to provide Bot ID while opening a task module through BOT. Please take a look at [Task Module with Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots) and [Task Module C# sample Code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-csharp). Let me know if you face any issue

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I did verify that the content can be iframed, and I did set the completionBotId in the response.  Was there something else that needed to be set with the response payload?

Comment: Completion bot id is required to fetch/task and task/submit actions. if you are doing chaining in task module you need to pass your defined action so you can achieve chaining.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed absolutely nothing in my bot, but this started working.  The code in the first post is identical (with the bot ID).  The only thing that's different is a Teams client update, so perhaps something got fixed in the application?

You have Microsoft Teams Version 1.2.00.34111 (64-bit)-E. It was last updated on 12/9/19.